# How do i Replace every n-th character x from an String

Tags: java, string, csv, replace

My Question would be how can replace every 3rd ';' from a String a put a ',' at this position ?

for eg.:

```
String s = "RED;34;34;BLUE;44;44;GREEN;8;8;BLUE;53;53"
```

so that the String looks like:

```
RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
```

I tried to solve it like this but i can't take a charAt(i) and replace it with an other char.

```
int counter =0;
for (int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    if(s.charAt(i) == ';'){

    counter++;
    }
    if(counter ==3){
    s.charAt(i)=',';
    counter =0;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome, have you tried something already? We can maybe begin from there to help you optimally

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/, e.g. looping through `char[]`, or using regex, or using `StringBuilder`, or using `indexOf`+`substring`, or ...

Comment: Split by semicolon, then join together, using comma instead of semicolon at every third word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally some own effort is demanded from the question, but regex is hard.

```
s = s.replaceAll("([^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*);", "$1,");
```

A sequence of 0 or more of not-semicolon followed by semicolon and such.

`[^ ...characters... ]` is some char *not* listed.

`...*` is zero or more of the immediately preceding match.

The match of the 1st group `(...)` is given in `$1`, so actually only the last semicolon is replaced by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

Not that elegant like by @Joop, but probably simplier to understand:

```
String s = "RED;34;34;BLUE;44;44;GREEN;8;8;BLUE;53;53";
char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
int counter = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
   if (chars[i] == ';'){
      if (counter == 3){
         chars[i] = ','; // replace ';' with ','
         counter = 1;    // set counter to 1
      }else {
         counter++;
      }
   }
}
String output = String.valueOf(chars);
System.out.println(output); // RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
```

Comment: This certainly will be faster than regex. With bulk data processing that could be significant

Answer (score 2):

You can use the modulo % operator to know the 3rd time something occurs. And a simple conversion between string and char array to do the rest:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        String s1 = "RED;34;34;BLUE;44;44;GREEN;8;8;BLUE;53;53";
        char [] s = s1.toCharArray();
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){    
        if (s[i]==';') {
           j++;    
           if(j % 3 == 0) {    
             s[i] = ',';    
          }     
       }
     }
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do it, as I suggested in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50332387/how-do-i-replace-every-n-th-character-x-from-an-string#comment87681032_50332387). Here are implementations of the ones I suggested, but there are of course more ways than this.

The first is the simplest, from a code point of view, if you know regex. See [answer by Joop Eggen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50332564/5221149) for an explanation.

The second is likely the fastest, especially if you eliminate the `%` modulo operator by resetting `j` to 0 instead.

```
private static String usingRegex(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("([^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*);", "$1,");
}

private static String usingCharArray(String s) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        if (arr[i] == ';' && ++j % 3 == 0)
            arr[i] = ',';
    return new String(arr);
}

private static String usingStringBuilder(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
        if (sb.charAt(i) == ';' && ++j % 3 == 0)
            sb.setCharAt(i, ',');
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String usingSubstring(String s) {
    int i = -1, j = 0;
    while ((i = s.indexOf(';', i + 1)) != -1)
        if (++j % 3 == 0)
            s = s.substring(0, i) + ',' + s.substring(i + 1);
    return s;
}
```

*Test*

```
String s = "RED;34;34;BLUE;44;44;GREEN;8;8;BLUE;53;53";
System.out.println(usingRegex(s));
System.out.println(usingCharArray(s));
System.out.println(usingStringBuilder(s));
System.out.println(usingSubstring(s));
```

*Output*

```
RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
RED;34;34,BLUE;44;44,GREEN;8;8,BLUE;53;53
```